# Invalid connection URL on Genexus generated code

Tags: java, genexus

I have created an application on Genexus 15 and imported the jar file generated on its deploy to a Java project on NetBeans.

When I call my sample procedure, I get the following error:

```
Error   : The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://:1433/' is invalid.
```

Looking at my client.cfg file, my DB_URL is as follows:

```
DB_URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TesteIntegracao
```

Since the connection code is generated by Genexus, I cannot access it to see where the URL is beeing created.

What is the source of this URL and the cause of the error?

Comment: Just to confirm: if you change the port in your `client.cfg` - say 1434 - does it reflect in error message?

Comment: Actually not, just tested it by changing and the file and creating a jar file on command line. Trying to figure out from where it creates thar URL

Comment: Could you try to copy the original client.cfg to your app root directory?

Comment: Hi @GonzaloGallotti. Thanks for the hint. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer with more detail, following the hint on comments above, I copied the client.cfg file to my java java root directory.

The original cfg file can be found inside the directories created by genexus when you deploy the application. It should be something like YourKB/JavaModel/Deploy/Local/

After this I had an error on my DB user, because it was encrypted in the client.cfg, so I just edited the USER_ID and USER_PASSWORD fields and the connection was successfull.

```
USER_ID=root
USER_PASSWORD=root

DB_URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TesteIntegracao
```

The other fields were kept with default value.